# Outlook Web Addin using native Search Box

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Using new Outlook Web Addins in Javascript, is possible to set values in global search box in outlook? I know that is possible using VSTO, but not sure if is possible throw js.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. Office.js doesn't provide anything for that.